# Can I use ": ," instead of ", implies" for this example?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

I've to write this statement in a formal manner:

> if $x>1$ then $x^{2}>1$.

Writing the result of the exercise I face this problem, I wonder if these two statements are equivalent:
$$\forall~x \in \mathbb{R}, x >1 \implies x^{2}>1 \ $$
$$\forall~x \in \mathbb{R}: x >1, ~~ x^{2}>1 \ $$

I read the first as:

> for all the x in $\mathbb{R}$ if x is greater than 1 then x squared is greater than 1

For the second I read it so:

> for all the x in $\mathbb{R}$ such that x is greater then 1, x squared is greater then 1

Where is my fault? Is there a better alternative?

---

Exercise 1.14-14 p.23 from *Analisi matematica vol.1* 3th ed. (2002) by *Enrico Giusti*

Comment: Please let me know the reason of the downvote...

Comment: Sorry ... I do not like your way of "symbolizing" the above formulae; what is the origin of the $\implies$ in the first one ? If in the second one $∀x∈R:x>1, x^2>1$ you are using the $∀x∈R: ...$ as a "restricted" quantifier abbreviating $∀x(x∈R \implies ...$, in the first formula (assuming that it means a "double restricted" quantifier ... which I think is a little bit convoluted) must be written as : $∀x∈R,x>1 : ...$. Thus the first formula (assuming that it is the abbreviation of $∀x ((x∈R \land x>1) \implies x^2>1)$ must be : $∀x∈R,x>1 : x^2>1$ ... which is quite *unredeable*.

Comment: Sorry ... "your fault" is that the english written sentences are much more clear to undestand that the symbiolic ones, and this is contrary to **all** usages of symbolic language. We use symbolic language **not** as a way to spare ink, but in order to avoid misunderstanding and ambiguity. If the people reading your formulae have problems understanding the correct meaning of the formulae (while your plain english is crystal clear), this means that ... you are using the sumbol in a wrong way.... :)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree with you but in fact the author of the first formula is Enrico Giusti that is is a well-respected professor in Italy. Can you propose a better alternative?

Comment: My suggestion would be to write this statement "$\forall x\in\mathbb R: x>1 \Rightarrow x^2>1$", where the colon reads as "it holds that" and not "such that".

Comment: @Christoph I thought this too, the problem is maybe that : is not used after $\forall$

Comment: You can use whatever notation whenever you like. Just make sure that whoever reads the text in the future can understand the meaning of that notation.

Comment: I've browse the italian edition of Enrico Giusti, *Analisi matematica. Vol 1 (2nd ed 1988); I cannot find the example in page 23...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Mine is 3nd ed 2002. Did you find exercise 1.14-14?

Comment: Sorry ... in the 2nd ed (1988) in page 23 the exercises go from 4.1 to 4.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These statemens aren't equivalent, at least the way I read them. I read the first as $$
  \forall x\,\left[\left((x \in \mathbb{R}) \land (x > 1)\right) \rightarrow x^2 > 1 \right] \text{,}
$$
which of course is true. The second, however, I read as $$
  \forall x \left[(x \in \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \left((x > 1) \land (x^2 > 1)\right)\right] \text{,}
$$
which is wrong, since $-1 \in \mathbb{R}$ but $x < 1$.

I'd say the general rule for reading such first-order formulas with extended syntax is that $$
  \forall x\,\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\ldots,\varphi_n\,:\, \theta
$$ 
means $$
  \forall x \left[\left(\varphi_1 \land \cdots \land \varphi_n\right) \rightarrow \theta\right] \text{,}
$$
i.e. in plain english that "For all $x$ such that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and ... $\varphi_n$, we have $\theta$".

Your first formula doesn't include a colon (:), and therefore doesn't really fit into that schema. But since the last comma-separated term is an implication, i.e. since it has the form $$
  \forall x\,\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n \rightarrow \theta 
$$
I'd say most people will read it as $$
    \forall x \left[\left(\varphi_1 \land \cdots \land \varphi_n\right) \rightarrow \theta\right] \text{.}
$$
But it really is a bit ambiguous, since another possible reading would be $$
    \forall x \left[\varphi_1 \land \cdots \land \varphi_{n-1} \land (\varphi_n \rightarrow \theta)\right] \text{.}
$$

Comment: +1 thanks a lot, I've edited the question. I don't understand how do you read the second statement...

Comment: There's nothing that indicates "such that $x > 1$" in the second formula. The colon does indicate "such that", but it's to the *left* of $x > 1$

Answer (score 2):

*This is only a "long" comment ...*

We start form the condition you are working with :

> if $x>1$ then $x^2>1$

where it is implicit that we are restricting the domain of discourse to $\mathbb R$.

We can easily symbolize it in an *unambiguos* manner as :

> *(a)* --- $\forall x(x \in \mathbb R \rightarrow (x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1))$.

A "standard" way to abbreviate this kind of fomulae is through the so-called "restricted quantifiers".

We may have :

*($a_1$)* --- $(\forall x \in \mathbb R)(x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1)$

or :

*($a_2$)* --- $(\forall x \in \mathbb R : x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1)$.

Both are exploiting the usual set-theoretic symbolism : $\{ x \in \mathbb R : \varphi(x) \}$.

When I read your first formula, I assume that you are using the comma (",") as a "separator", like the colon (":") in my formula ($a_2$), and it's all right for me.

When I read your second formula :

> $∀x∈R : x>1, x^2>1$

I assume that now you are using the colon (":") as "separator". But what is the role of the comma (",") ? It is also a "separator" ? of what ? or it takes the place of a *connective*...

Thus, we have too many possibilities :

*($b_1$)* --- $(∀x∈R)(x>1, x^2>1)$

and we may suppose that the comma is $\land$;

or we can read it as :

*($b_2$)* --- $(∀x∈R : x>1)(x^2>1)$.

This the source of my "disappointment" with the "double restricted" quantifier; we have to read it as ($a_2$) above :

*($b_3$)* --- $∀x(x∈R \land x>1 : x^2>1)$

i.e. as

*($b_4$)* --- $∀x((x∈R \land x>1) \rightarrow x^2>1)$ ?

But this one is different from ($b_1$) which, written *in extenso*, is :

$∀x(x∈R \rightarrow (x>1 \land x^2>1))$.

But if we read the comma in ($b_1$) as $\rightarrow$, we have :

*($b_5$)* --- $∀x(x∈R \rightarrow (x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1))$

and this **is** equivalent to ($b_4$).

Thus my conclusion is :

- stay with **standard** symbolism; commas and colons are **not** connectives but "separators"
- and we have already "standard" separators : the parentheses.

Comment: In fact of course I've used comma in the second formula as a separator you can deduce from the plain english explanation. At this point I think is better don't use comma at all, even if indeed is used a lot as separator or as connective in literature but from what I see the question was legitimate.

Comment: @GM - right ! if both comma and colon are separators, and we stay with the "standard" convention regarding "restricted" quantifiers, we have that $∀x∈R:x>1, x^2>1$ , read as ($b_2$) above, becomes : $((∀x∈R:x>1) \rightarrow x^2>1)$ i.e. $(∀x∈R)(x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1)$ i.e. $(∀x)(x∈R \rightarrow x>1 \rightarrow x^2>1)$ and we clearly have problems in restoring the "precedence" between connectives.

Comment: thanks +1, so in my second formula I'used restricted quntifiers (`:` as `such that`) and comma as separator. So in this case the second formula is equivalent to the first I copied from the book or not?

Comment: @GM - my "feeling" is that if you "disambiguate" $∀x∈R:x>1,x^2>1$ as $((∀x∈R:x>1)→x^2>1)$, which in turn is $(∀x∈R)(x>1→x^2>1)$, we obtain : $∀x(x∈R \rightarrow (x>1→x^2>1))$, which is my *(a)* above, i.e. equivalent to your first formula. **But** there is nowhere a rule or convention which says that it is so and not the other possibility, i.e. from your formula to $((∀x∈R:x>1)→x^2>1)$ to $∀x((x∈R \rightarrow x>1)→x^2>1)$, which is not.